# How to receive data from a port and show in a C# windows form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, xbee

I am doing two port communication using the `XBEE` module. I am sending and receiving the value using a C# Windows form.

The sending code is working perfectly:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        SerialPort port1 = new SerialPort("COM28", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        port1.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        port1.Open();
        port1.Write("Hello");
        port1.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
          MessageBox.Show(""+ex);
        }
    }
```

The receiver side is unable to receive the message. The code is working in a console application; but when I try to code this in a Windows form, it's not working:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM29");

        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;



        mySerialPort.Open();
        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
        mySerialPort.Close();

    }
    private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        MessageBox.Show("Data received");
        MessageBox.Show(indata);
    }
```

Comment: Try to remove mySerialPort.Close() in button1_Click (receive part)

Comment: try to define mySerialPort in class, not in method.

Comment: You can try to use ReadExisting in button1_Click without firing DataReceiveHandler event. If you want to use DataReceiveHandler, you should remove it because I think it is not disposed by compiler. Everytime you click the button1, a new event is created without disposing the latest. Anyway, using a breakpoint, have you verified if the code reaches "string indata.."?

Comment: No wonder it isn't receiving any data. As soon as you open the COM port, you close it. Perhaps it would be better if you explained what it *should* do.

Comment: @Emi987 I tried using break point.The code doesn't reaches DataReceivedHandler method

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because... the OP hasn't bothered to read what they (most likely have not) written!

Comment: And... Where does it hang?

Comment: @Emi987 It goes to "mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);" and suddenly goes to mySerialPort.close();. It doesn't call DataReceivedHandler method.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, you copied the example in msdn page about `SerialPort`. 
It works on ConsoleApplication becuase it never goes to `mySerialPort.Close();` because
the little app is waiting for an input ( Look at `Console.ReadKey();`).
In this case, the code has the time to handle the `DataReceivedHandler` and display the string stored in `indata`.
In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590945/how-to-display-the-data-read-in-datareceived-event-handler-of-serialport?rq=1), another user has the same problem as you and he has been suggested to use `Delegate`. I don't know it is exactly your case, but it can help you.
You can even try to not use `DataReceivedHandler`. For instance, you can try something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM29");

    mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
    mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
    mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
    mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

    mySerialPort.Open();
    /*If the read buffer is not empty, indata will not be an empty string*/
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting(); //You can even use sp.ReadLine() and see if it changes something
    MessageBox.Show("Data received");
    MessageBox.Show(indata);
    mySerialPort.Close();

}
```

Let's see if this may help you!